# No Intellisense for Doubly Linked List Template

Tags: c++, templates, visual-studio-2013, intellisense

I am new to templates in C++ and am working on a project where I need to implement a Doubly Linked List using a template. However, I can't seem to access the node elements next and previous.

For example, in my destructor, I cannot use curr-> to bring up my options of using next or prev. IntelliSense just says, "No members available." Also, I can only find errors during build time...no red lines, warnings, anything appear beforehand. I am curious as to why this is not working....is it a bug or intended? If it is, where is my template incorrect thus far?

```
template<class ItemType>
class SortedList
{
public:
   SortedList();
   ~SortedList();
   bool Insert (ItemType toAdd);
   bool Delete (ItemType toDelete);
   void Print();

private:
   SortedList ( const SortedList & copyFrom );
   SortedList & operator= ( const SortedList & assignFrom );

   struct Node
   {
      Node ( ItemType item, Node * p = NULL, Node * n = NULL )
      { data = item; prev = p; next = n; }
      ItemType data;
      Node * prev, * next;
   };
   Node * list;
};

template<class ItemType>
SortedList<ItemType>::SortedList()
{
   list = NULL;
}

template<class ItemType>
SortedList<ItemType>::~SortedList()
{
   Node * curr = list;
   while ( curr != NULL )
   {
      Node * tempNext = curr->next;
      delete curr;
      curr = tempNext;
   }
}
```

Comment: It may help if you include the exact error from the compiler?

Comment: What environment are you using? Which IDE?

Comment: I am using Visual Studio 2012. IntelliSense is working in all other projects.

I am not getting compile errors. That is why I am confused. In my .cpp file, all I have is an include of the template, as well as a test bed main which does SortedList<int> list;

Comment: If you need more info on C++ templates check out this link http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cplusplus/cpp_templates.htm

Comment: @user2989526. If your compiler is happy, then you are happy. Intellisense is nice, but if it's not yet picking up the members, try delete the Intellisense file and restart the IDE. Sometimes it's happy to help, sometimes not (I've had issues with nested classes).

Comment: Tried deleting the SDF file and restarting, still get the same "No member's available" when using ->. Seems to only do that when I'm using a template implemented what seems to be correctly. I just felt it was really strange that it can't identify the members of my Node struct.

Answer (score 0):

Put the `Node` struct out of the `SortedList` like this:

```
template<typename ItemType>
struct Node
{
    Node(ItemType item, Node * p = NULL, Node * n = NULL)
    {
        data = item; prev = p; next = n;
    }
    ItemType data;
    Node * prev, *next;
};
```

and then instantiate the template (create the type) inside `SortedList` like this:

```
template<class ItemType>
class SortedList
{
public:
    //... More code here.

private:
    // ... More code here.
    Node<ItemType> * list;
};

template<class ItemType>
SortedList<ItemType>::SortedList()
{
    list = NULL;
}

template<class ItemType>
SortedList<ItemType>::~SortedList()
{
    Node<ItemType> *curr = list;

    while (curr != NULL)
    {
        Node * tempNext = curr->next; // Now this will work.
        delete curr;
        curr = tempNext;
    }
}
```

### The logic I have followed

A template, is not a type. You get the type instantiating the template. Hence the type `Node` Does not exists until you instantiate the template `StortedList` since the former is inside the latter.

Also the exact type for `Node` would be `SortedList<ItemType>::Node`, and there you can see you can't talk about `Node`, before compiling the code. Thats why IntelliSense don't "see it".

Comment: Thank you, I'll check it out in a couple hours when I get back online. By any chance, can you explain why this would work, if it does, and not the other way around?

Comment: I post the loginc I've  followed